# После переноса WordPress с одного сервера на другой перестала работать админка

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cms

Выдает ошибки:

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'infouniy_vladivi.wp_gg_stats' doesn't exist]
SELECT * FROM wp_gg_stats

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/i/infouniy/vladivid.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1309) in /home/i/infouniy/vladivid.com/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196
```

Ошибка с `wp_gg_stats` была и на прошлом сервере, не нашел где эта таблица запрашивается.

`function.php` и `wp-config.php` на предмет лишних пробелов/символов перед `< ?php` проверял, всё нормально, лишних знаков нет.

Comment: 1) проверь права доступа к файлам и папкам - из-за них вечно какая-то фигня случается
2) Ты каким образом файлы переносил? Через фтп или как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вам в в ошибке сообщается, что не существует таблица  `infouniy_vladivi.wp_gg_stats`.
А во-вторых, поводу пробелов и прочего, вам их искать надо не в файлах `function.php` и `wp-config.php`, а в `/home/i/infouniy/vladivid.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php`, как указано в ошибке с хедером.